# Создание списка на основе JSON

Tags: jquery, json, ajax

jQuery в ответ на запрос получает JSON-строку типа

```
{36:"Австралия",40:"Австрия"}
```

Фрагмент jQuery:

```
$.ajax ({
  type: "GET",
  url: "/ajax/",
  data: "q=" + query,
  cache: false,
  dataType: 'json',
  success: function(response) {

    // генерация bar на основе response

    $("#foo").html(bar);
  } 
});
```

Из полученного JSON хочется собрать фрагмент HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li id='36'>Австралия</li>
  <li id='40'>Австрия</li>
</ul>
```

И добавить внутрь div'а "foo".

Хочется не столько увидеть решение, сколько понять логику работы jQuery с JSON.

Comment: Кручусь вокруг этого: 

    <...>
    success: function(response) {
      var bar = '';
      $.each(response, function(key, val){
        var bar += '<li id="' + key + '">' + val + '</li>';
      });

      $("#foo").html(bar);
      <...> 

Пока безуспешно.

Comment: Синтаксическая ошибка же

    var bar += ... // уберите var

Comment: Убрал. Не взлетело.

Comment: Не стоит использовать аттрибут `id` для записи `id` в базе. Для этого лучше писать в `data-id`

Comment: Моё личное мнение - формировать HTML-код лучше в PHP, а делать эту работу на стороне клиента как-то неуместно.

Comment: поставьте firebug для лисы, в oper'е есть dragonfly, в хроме и ie жмите f12, для safari есть firebug lite правда глючный немного )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо всем за варианты решения. Остановился на этом:

```
var items = '';
$.getJSON("/ajax/", "q=" + query, function(response) {
  $.each(response, function(i,val) {
    items += '<li id="' + i + '">' + val + '</li>';
  });
  $('#foo').html(items);
});
```

Проблема решилась изменением положения строк

```
var items = '';
```

и

```
$('#foo').html(items);
```

Проблема, как я понял, была в видимости переменной items для $('#foo').html(items). Выручил alert(), который я ставил всюду, где только можно, чтобы визуализировать данные на разных этапах. Еще один косяк - невалидный JSON: обернул ID кавычками.

Answer (score 2):

```
success: function(response) {
var ul = $('<ul></ul>')
   for(i=0;i<response.length;i++){
   $('<li id='+response[i][0]+'>'+response[i][1]+'</li>').appendTo(ul);
}
  }
```

но так json данные не должны приходить, они должны выглядеть примерно так

```
{countryID:36, countryName:'Австралия'}
```

Comment: Вариант {countryID:36, countryName:'Австралия'} очень смущает по сравнению с {36:"Австралия",40:"Австрия"}. Во второй вмещается данных в 2-2.5 раза больше. Да и в плане семантическом у первого варианта выигрыша никакого - структура данных прозрачна: ключ-значение.

Answer (score 2):

Начинать проверку надо с response. Проблема у вас с JSON'ом.
Он не валидный. Воспользуйтесь [валидатором](http://json.parser.online.fr/).
Дело в том, что для получения json объекта в `$.ajax`, jQuery использует функцию `$.parseJSON()`, которая выдает ошибку на ваш json:

```
Unhandled Error: JSON.parse: Property name (in double quotes) expected: 36:
```

Исправьте json, все будет работать.

NB:

> Important: As of jQuery 1.4, if the
> JSON file contains a syntax error, the
> request will usually fail silently.
> Avoid frequent hand-editing of JSON
> data for this reason. JSON is a
> data-interchange format with syntax
> rules that are stricter than those of
> JavaScript's object literal notation.
> For example, all strings represented
> in JSON, whether they are properties
> or values, must be enclosed in
> double-quotes. For details on the JSON
> format, see http://json.org/.

Comment: Да. Учту эту тонкость с кавычками. С ними вообще интересно в jQuery, как я понял.

Comment: ну такую ошибку даст не только $.parseJSON но и JSON.parse из [json2.js][1]

[1]:http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js

Answer (score 1):

Я бы сделал так:

```
var $ul = $('<ul>');
for (var id in response) {
    var $li = $('<li>');
    $li.attr('id', id);
    $li.html(response[id]);
    $ul.append($li);
}
// ну и ещё можно
$('#foo').append($ul);
```

Comment: такой метод медленно работает, лучше строку собирать, и один раз делать

    $("#foo").html(ulstr)

Answer (score 0):

Можно с *извратом* сделать примерно так :)

```
var data_mas = eval('('+response+')');
 var sum_elem=data_mas.length;
 var print,num=0;
  while (n < sum_elem) 
  {
   bar +='blablabla'+data_mas[0];
  n++;
  }
  $("#foo").html(bar);
```

Comment: > eval('('+response+')')

Слышал ужастики как перехватывают ajax-запросы и присылают произвольный js-код?

Comment: Слышал, слышал, я же написал "извратом" :)

Comment: зачем постить код плохого качества?

Comment: @Vladimir VG а кто мешает его не использовать. Я дал вариант решения.

А про

>зачем постить код плохого качества?

Так же можно и в салон "ВАЗа" зайти, купить машину и через неделю она сломается, и что салону предъявишь "Зачем вы продаете машину плохого качества", что ответят? Правильно - "Если не устраивает - зачем купили?"